# What is the default CORS setting for ExpressJS?

Tags: express, cors, fetch-api

I am making an ExpressJS that responds to post data that can be sent from any origin. But when I use the fetch API to send post data from a random site, It gives me a CORS error. When I google how to disable CORS in express, it gives me a bunch of results on how to *enable* CORS. This makes me very confused. **What is the default setting for CORS in express, and do I need to disable it?**. The error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/api' from origin 'https://www.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Also, what does `If an opaque response serves your needs` mean?

Comment: Unless you're using the [Express cors middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) (whose default config is [available in the doc](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuration-options)), Express itself isn't configured for CORS. An _opaque response_ is a response to a request whose [`mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#mode) is `no-cors`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use cors() middleware,

```
const app = express();
const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    methods: [],
    allowedHeaders: [],
    exposedHeaders: [],
    credentials: true
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

});
```

[See details about cors module here,](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) will help to have configuration based on your requirement.

Comment: Great answer, but I am asking about the default setting for CORS in express assuming I am not using any CORS middleware

Comment: Disabled by default express or probably any other web (rest) api framework. Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is an HTTP-header based mechanism that allows a server to indicate any origins (domain or port) other than its own from which a browser should permit loading resources. In client server architecture, if client app domain host url different than its server browser doesn't consider it's a safe communication so blocks it in that case server should whitelist allowed host domain with a CORS settings. If client and server on same domain (host url) it's not required at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
import express = require("express");
const app = express()
import path = require('path')
require('dotenv').config({path: path.join(__dirname, '../.env')})
const port = process.env.API_PORT
import cors = require('cors')
import bodyParser = require('body-parser')


const main = async () => {

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors({origin: process.env.FRONTEND_SERVER, credentials: true}))

// app routes

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}/api`)
})
}

main()
```